# Efficient nonlinear discrete multivariable optimization in R

Tags: r

I have a function which is extremely computationally heavy (takes about 10 minutes to run once), and this function has 4 parameters.

I define the function as follows

```
function <- function(parameters){...calculate value...    
return(value)
}
```

It is nonlinear for sure, and these 4 parameters I am defining must be integer values. I want to run it on the interval from `c(3, 100, 20000, 80000)` to `c(10, 150, 80000, 120000)`

I realize that for a function which is this computationally heavy and the range is so large, this will take a long time for analysis.

I am looking for an efficient way of doing this. `rgenoud` seems to work for integer values, but after running it, I have no way to determine if it is actually running. It stops on the line `Minimization problem`.

Are there other such optimization algorithms (either minimization or maximization) which are extremely efficient and will give me some feedback whether it is running or not?

I am sorry I could not provide a reproducible example, as I cannot provide the data set (100 gb) and this is more of a theoretical question.

EDIT:

If this helps, some algorithms I have been looking at include genetic algorithms, swarm particle optimization, simulated annealing, Markov chain Monte Carlo. I am open to other algorithms, as I am just looking for most efficient way to optimize these discrete variables.

EDIT 2:
Simplified version of function:

```
control1 <- sample(1:75, 3947398, replace=TRUE)
control2 <- sample(1:75, 28793, replace=TRUE)
control3 <- sample(1:100, 392733, replace=TRUE)
control4 <- sample(1:75, 858383, replace=TRUE)
patient1 <- sample(1:100, 28048, replace=TRUE)
patient2 <- sample(1:50, 80400, replace=TRUE)
patient3 <- sample(1:100, 48239, replace=TRUE)
control <- list(control1, control2, control3, control4)
patient <- list(patient1, patient2, patient3)

function <- function(parameter){
s <- parameter[1]
control_s <- list()
patient_s <- list()
for (i in 1:length(control))
        control_s[[i]] <- sample(control[[i]], s)
for (i in 1:length(patient))
        patient_s[[i]] <- sample(patient[[i]], s)
controlfreq <- list()
for (i in 1:length(control_s)){
controlfreq[[i]] <-
    as.data.frame(prop.table(table(factor(
        control_s[[i]], levels = 1:100
    ))))[,2]}
patientfreq <- list()
for (i in 1:length(patient_s)){
patientfreq[[i]] <-
    as.data.frame(prop.table(table(factor(
        patient_s[[i]], levels = 1:100
    ))))[,2]}
controlfreq <- t(as.data.frame(controlfreq))
controltrainingset <- transform(controlfreq, status = "control")
patientfreq <- t(as.data.frame(patientfreq))
patienttrainingset <- transform(patientfreq, status = "patient")

dataset <- rbind(controltrainingset, patienttrainingset)

library(caret)
fitControl <-trainControl(method = "LOOCV", classProbs = T, savePredictions = T)
model <- train(status ~ ., data = dataset, method = "rf", trControl = fitControl)

selectedIndices <- model$pred$mtry == 2
confusionmatrix <- table(model$pred$obs[selectedIndices], model$pred$pred[selectedIndices])
metric= ((confusionmatrix[1,1]/length(control))+(confusionmatrix[2,2]/length(patient)))/2

return(-metric)}

# -metric if minimizing, metric if maximizing
```

Comment: Could you provide a small sample?

Comment: @JosephWood Unfortunately not. I could try and explain what the function is trying to do however. I am trying to classify collections of sequences using glmnet. The parameters of interest change the number of characters that make up each feature, the number of clusters made out of each of these character strings, the number of character strings sampled from each sample, and the number of strings that must be present for a sample to be included in analysis. This function is computationally heavy, so I am looking for an efficient way to maximize (or minimize the negative) of the functions output

Comment: @JosephWood I don't know if it would help, but I added some other examples of algorithms I was looking at under EDIT above. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Without seeing any data or example we are shooting in the dark... Have you looked into `Rcpp`?  Is there any way you could show us the guts of the function?

Comment: I just added a simplified version of my function. This only contains one variable to be optimized, but I imagine it would be similar if it was several variables (I input a vector, then assign variables based on position in vector as seen above). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @JosephWood If you would like clarification on any part please let me know.